# timed_penalty_date on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, data-explorer

I just did a [query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/271/track-excessive-downvoters) to list user with higest downvote ratio. Then I noticed that there is banned user like "[Geoffrey Chetwood](https://superuser.com/users/904)".

Would it be possible to include this information on Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

I saw that it's [available using the API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/help/method?method=users) so I guess it would be good to have it in dumps for consistency between ways to retrieve SE data.

Comment: [This query in SEDE](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5987/boxed-users) gets close to finding boxed users.

Comment: Btw, I know almost no sql.  So, deal with the crappy query...

Answer (score 5):

I don't think publicizing this information is a great idea.  Being able to easily look for suspended users doesn't seem like a good use of the data explorer.

I know it is interesting to see someone that is boxed, but it is really not any of our business why or for how long.

My vote goes to leaving it out.  I can't see any value added by it.

Answer (score 4):

Given that this is (a) public information (could be retrieved by scraping), and (b) available using the API, I think this field should be included in the data dump as well.

I would imagine that The Management had a discussion over that field before including it in the API, so I think following that same decision would be a good plan.

Yes, I agree that perhaps it isn't the best idea to allow searching for users who are in the penalty box, but if you're determined enough to find those users, you can anyway. All you have to do is search for users who have gained a bunch of rep, but still have a displayed rep of 1.

Conversely, I can't think of a reason to *exclude* it either. The penalty box isn't a place a user should want to be, so this might be a little bit of extra encouragement to stay out of it.